# Prove $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$ where $P(\emptyset)$ is the power set of the empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

My doubt is whether or not it's advisable to harness a lemma in this proof so that it reads more smoothly. The aforesaid lemma would read:

> **Lemma**: $\exists!\, S:S\subseteq \emptyset$

***Proof.*** By virtue our lemma, indeed$$\forall x:\big(x\subseteq \emptyset \iff x=\emptyset\big)\iff \forall x:\big(x\in P(\emptyset)\iff x\in \{\emptyset\}\big)\iff P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$$

Comment: @DonThousand Are you reading $\exists!$ as "there's no"? I think it's usually read as "there's exactly one" (or possibly "there's at most one" in some sources).

Comment: Do you know a proof of your lemma?

Comment: @J.G. Yes (In case it's true).

Comment: I don't understand your aside. Either you know a proof - so it's true - or you don't.

Comment: @J.G. Is there $S\ne \emptyset:S\subseteq \emptyset$?

Comment: Well, no, but can you _prove_ that? If not, your "lemma" pretty much assumes what you're ultimately trying to prove. On the other hand, if you, can the proof strategy would be easily adapted to solving the original problem directly.

Comment: @J.G Is the prove strategy advisable? Or should I just prove it without using a lemma, which of course is easy?

Comment: The lemma is not false, but just totally unnecessary to rely on, in that it is completely equivalent to the statement you want to prove

Comment: @DonThousand Don't treat yourself like that, I aprecciate your hardest effort to enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of your latest comment, I'll explain why I think the result's proof should be presented without stating the proposed lemma.

Since the desired theorem may be stated as $\forall x(x\subseteq\emptyset\iff x=\emptyset)$, the stated lemma is the crux of the problem, but we can argue as follows directly (as I think you probably already know):

> The $\Longleftarrow$ direction is trivial; for the $\implies$ direction, note if $x\subseteq\emptyset$ then there are no elements of $x$ (as they'd also be elements of $\emptyset$), so $x=\emptyset$ by extensionality.

That looks simple enough to me. If anything, I'd rather regard the lemma as a restatement of this direct result. Indeed, one would usually prove a theorem of the form $\forall x(\varphi(x)\iff x=a)$, then note $\exists!x(\varphi(x))$ as a corollary. (In your case, the corollary makes obvious the identity of $a$ - because its choice of $\varphi$ is the second-argument-fixed case of an unsaturated ordering relation - but that doesn't change my recommendation.) How else would one get to the latter, especially with pedagogical clarity?